# Assigning a macro in EXCEL some VBA code to DELETE rows where specified cells are blank

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a macro to delete all rows with blank cells in row "F".

Here is my code:

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()
    On Error Resume Next
    Range([indirect("V1")]).Select.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

The indirect(V1) refers to a variable which indicates what range to work in. Currently cell V1 contains `Materjal!F1:F191`.

But after applying the code to a button, when i click it, it only SELECTS the range, but does not remove the rows with empty cell values.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Do you mind trying `Range([indirect("V1")]).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete` instead of `Range([indirect("V1")]).Select.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: Select is a command. Everything after that command is ignored. Use the formula Ralph wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
fRange = Range(Cells(1,"F"),Cells(.CountRows,"F"))
If fRange = "" Then
 Cells(.countRows,"F").EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Is this working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim last As Integer

last = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

''select unused column
Range("AA1").Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(F1 = """", ""Y"", ""N"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA1:AA" & last)
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


Range("AA1").Select
For i = 1 To last

    If Selection.Value = "Y" Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If


Next

Columns("AA:AA").ClearContents

End Sub
```